# How to know the user edited?

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using Blazor server-side with ASP.NET Core 5 and EF Core 5. I would like that when a record is updated than the `ModifiedBy` and `CreatedBy` are generated automatically.

I have overriden `SaveChangeAsync` as follows:

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ApplyInterfaces();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}

private void ApplyInterfaces()
{
    var userId = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
    var currentUsername = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)? userId: "Anonymous";

    foreach (ICreatedBy entity in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is ICreatedBy).Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added).Select(x=> x.Entity))
    {
        entity.CreatedBy = currentUsername;
        entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    foreach (IModifiedBy entity  in  ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x=> x.State == EntityState.Modified).Where(x => x.Entity is IModifiedBy).Select(x => x.Entity))
    {
        entity.ModifiedBy = currentUsername;
        entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

`_httpContextAccessor` is injected to the `DBContext`. I added the services

```
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Everything works fine on IIS Express. But when I publish to IIS `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` is null.

Where did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `IHttpContextAccessor` in Blazor apps ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-and-shared-state)).

It's not clear from your code sample if this code is in a Blazor component/page or in a database access library. If it's in the database layer you should modify  `SaveChangesAsync` to add a `string username` parameter, which you can then pass to `ApplyInterfaces`.

Getting the user should be the responsibility of the Blazor page/component, using either [AuthenticationStateProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.authorization.authenticationstateprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or an `AuthorizeView` component.

```cs
@page "/example"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider auth;

<button @OnClick="Save">Save</button>

@code 
{
   async Task Save()
   {
      var state = await auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
      var username = state.User.Identity?.Name ?? "[anon]";
      await someObject.SaveChangesAsync(username);
   }
}
```

Comment: it is on database access

Comment: A database access layer should not be using a `HttpContext` to get a user - you're mixing up different layers and not separating concerns. Whatever code you use to create the data context should have a service passed in that the DB can call to get the current user, e.g. `IUserAccessService` or something.

Comment: IUserAccessService  should be scoped... right? and again what should be injected into IUserAccessService to know the user? HttpContext is not working neither. Shall I try to inject AuthenticationStateProvider  in it ...

Comment: How do you get a database context?

Comment: I wanted to use ICrud datalayer with db context inside for now on. Because in future I will move on  remote  API layer service. Anyhow it is a little bit strange that I must pass  usernmae to the datalayer in this way context.SaveChangesAsync(username) or datalayer.Update(data, username)